# SwiftUI: Is it possible to live stream the screen?

Tags: swiftui, screen, live-streaming

This is a rather simple question, so I was wondering if it’s possible to livestream the users screen?
I also want the livestream to be possible outside of my app, meaning the home page and other apps.

**Is something like this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably best way is by using a multimedia adapter and a connecting its output to an HDMI audio/video capture card.

Not a software problem, and definitely not related to SwiftUI: can be solved by using hardware.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I’m asking how I can create an app with which the user can stream their screen to other users using that app. I want to achieve this without any extra hardware